# rutimeerror maximum recursion depth exceeded when creating a view

Tags: flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I have these 2 forms which appear on one single page (`dashboard.html`)

```
# Forms.py

class Area(Form):
    title = TextField("Title", [validators.Required("Please enter an Area Title")])
    text = TextAreaField("Text (max 50 characters)",[validators.Required("Please enter an Area text"),validators.Length(max=50,message="Area text cannot be more than 50 characters")])

class Message(Form):
    Message_title = TextField("Title", [validators.Required("Please enter a Message Title")])
    Message_Date_and_Time = DateTimeField("Date and Time")
```

And I'm trying to create 3 views to take care of all cases:

- when I display `dashboard.html` when getting to the page initially ([GET])
- when the user sends the `Area` form (so he obtains validation or error messages depending on the validation) ([POST])
- when the user sends the `Message` form (so he obtains validation or error messages depending on the validation) ([POST])

For that I have the following code:

```
@app.route('/dashboard.html')
def dashboard():
    return render_template('dashboard.html',form= Area(),M_form = Message())

@app.route('/Area',methods=['POST'])
def Area():
    return render_template('dashboard.html', form= Area(), M_form=Message())

@app.route('/Message',methods=['POST'])
def Area():
    return render_template('dashboard.html', form= Area(), M_form=Message())
```

But when I try to load any of these 3 views I get a `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded` error and the traceback is

```
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)  
...., line 24, in dashboard  
return render_template('dashboard.html', form= Area(), M_form = Message())  
...., line 31, in Area  
return render_template('dashboard.html', form= Area(), N_form = Message())  
...., line 31, in Area  
return render_template('dashboard.html', form= Area(), N_form = Message())
```

The same error again and again until it reaches its clock limit.

And when I just use the dashboard view (after removing both `/Area` and `/Message` views altogether from the code) it works just fine. I get my `dashboard.html`.

I've been looking around, I can t find any connection between the `runtimeerror: maximum recursion` and forms or WTforms. It seems to be always in connection with a loop not properly closed but here I have no loop. I can't see where its coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have same name for the `Area` form and the view functions (`/Area` and `/Message`). You're getting the recursion depth error because inside the view function name `Area`, you are calling `Area()` again to generate the form but instead the view function is called back in recursion infinitely.

```
@app.route('/Area',methods=['POST'])
def Area():
    # Area() is called below and it refers to this view function itself
    # that was just declared above.
    return render_template('dashboard.html', form= Area(), M_form=Message())
```

Change the names of the view functions to something different and unique.